# API call to map geo coordinates to altitude

Tags: api, altitude

Does HERE has an API that is able to map goe contains (latitude and longitude pair) to the altitude?

Comment: i dont get the question .... if you are at Lat: 0°00"00', Lon: 0°00"00' you need to turn that into an "Altitude" information????

Comment: Yes, I want to know altitude at a given geocoordinates. Similar to following google maps API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/overview